# Parsing FETCH multiple UID

Tags: imap, envelope

I need to write an IMAP code to parse the result of this command:

```
tag FETCH 1,2,3,4 ALL
```

Most of the time, the response is something like this

```
* 1 FETCH (FLAGS ... ) ENVELOPE ("time" "subject" ... )\r\n
* 2 FETCH (FLAGS ... ) ENVELOPE ("time" "subject" ... )\r\n
....
tag OK FETCH COMPLETE
```

And so on where each Envelope starts with asterik UID, and end with a CRLF, so I can use the CRLF as a parse point.

The problem is some servers are responding to me using IMAP string literals, ie {150}\r\n .... and since the \r\n is part of the string literal I can no longer use it as a parse point.

One idea is to use the * UID as a parsepoint, but if someone coincidentally uses that as an email subject, or whatnot, it will break the algo so I believe its a bad idea to do that.

Can someone tell me how to effectively parse this type of response without using CRLF? Most thanks you very much.

edit - Hopefully to improve question, I am trying to parse each individual ENVELOPE into it's own string based on parse points, where I need a parsepoint that identifies the start of one string and the end of another.

Answer (score 0):

The trick you need is one to distinguish the two kinds of line feeds, and it exists: Start reading, read until you see a CRLF, then look at the start of what you have. Is it tag space OK, NO, BAD or PREAUTH? If so, you have a complete response. If not, look at the last 10-15 characters. Are they "{", a number, optionally a plus sign, and "}" and the CRLF? If so, read until the next CRLF and repeat. If not, you have a complete response.

Note that in IMAP, you have to act on a response before you can parse the next one. MSN handling breaks if you don't, there may be other problems too.

Comment: Thanks arnt. The 2nd part of your answer is right, I need to look for CRLF that do not come after }. However, for the 1st part of your answer, the OK, NO, BAD only comes one time at the end of FETCH. Thus it is to you can FETCH 1000 envelopes and there will only be one OK at the end so these cannot be no parsepoints.

Comment: Also, why you say you have to act on a response before handle next one? What u mean?

Comment: Uh, there has to be a tagged OK at the end, but the server can send as many untagged extra OK responses as it wants, for any reason it wants. Common reasons include wanting to send a response code and defeat NAT middleboxes. And when you send A UID FETCH 1000:1200 ..., you may get * FETCH, * EXPUNGE, * FETCH, A OK. (Or you may get * FETCH, * OK [VANISHED], * FETCH, A OK if RFC7162 is in use.) The correct parsing of the second FETCH depends on the processing of the intervening EXPUNGE (or VANISHED).

Comment: And note that the server can, and often does, send FETCH resposes for messages you didn't ask for. Try to read mail with another client meanwhile: The server will tell both clients when the \seen flag has been set, even if one didn't actually ask to be told.